# Location of uploaded file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a file uploader using JavaScript which can uploads a single file. I used this code

```
<input type="file" id="myFile">
```

I am quite new to JavaScript. I need to know where does this uploaded file get stored.

Comment: open that html in browser. Upload file and check where  it is saved.

Comment: There's no backend to process this, so your file isn't really uploaded anywhere.

Comment: You will need to learn some server side language to understand fileuploading. or working of any form data.

Comment: hi dude this html code will allows you to pick a file on your page but if you want to save that file you need to have write your own code to handle that

Comment: Without the `<form>` tag it's impossible to know where it might get saved or without the javascript code that save the file. The input tag doesn't save anything anywhere, it's just an interface that allow the html to access files.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload a file to the server you need to learn about **any one** of the server side technology. For example: [PHP](http://php.net/), [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), [Python](https://www.python.org/). Or if you want a backend in javascript take a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) is a tutorial for uploading a file in PHP language.